# Find the coefficients of a polynomial given a tangent

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Can someone help me with this problem please? (Thanks in advance):

The graph of $y=3x$ is tangent to $f(x)=2x^2-ax+b$ at $x=2$. Find the values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y=3x$ is tangent to $f(x)$ at $x=2$, then $f(x)$ has slope $3$ at $x=2$. To find the slope, we differentiate $f$ and evaluate at 2 to get $3=f'(2)=8-a$, so $a=5$. To find $b$, we note that if $f$ is tangent to $y=3x$ at $x=2$, then it must pass through $(2,y(2))=(2,6)$. Setting $f(2)=2\cdot 2^2 -5 \cdot 2 + b = 6$, we get $b=8$.

Answer (score 0):

A few hints:

1) Given a curve $f(x)$, how do you compute the slope at a point $P$ on the curve?
If $y = 3x$ is a tangent at P, what is the slope at point P from this information?

2) If the line $y = 3x$ and the curve $y = 2x^2 - ax + b$ meet, they have to meet at exactly one point. So what can you say about the roots of the quadratic equation $3x = 2x^2 - ax + b$?